# Postgresql дата и приведение типов

Tags: sql, postgresql

> Чтобы «сказать» СУБД, что введенное значение является датой, а не
>   простой сим- вольной строкой, мы использовали операцию приведения
>   типа. В PostgreSQL она оформляется с использованием двойного символа
>   «двоеточие» и имени того типа, к которому мы приводим данное значение.

Вот пример:

```
SELECT '2016-09-12'::date;
```

Я просто не до конца понимаю.
Вот пример: 
1. `create table users (id serial, name varchar, date_start date);` - создаем таблицу
2. `insert into users (name, date_start) values ('Petya', '2018-02-23');` - добавляем пользователя и дату когда он записался.
Хотелось бы спросить, в данном примере у меня хранится дата или строка? Я после прочтения выше сказанной цитаты начал сомневаться. Знаю что такое приведение типов, но не очень понимаю как в Postgresql правильно "создать" столбец с типом дата.
`SELECT '2016-09-12'::date;` 
Или просто `'2016-09-12'` так?

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос важный и потому ему посвящён отдельный раздел документации: [Chapter 10. Type Conversion](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/typeconv.html)

Когда вы пишете в запросе `'2016-09-12'` - парсер запроса видит некий литерал и для начала считает что это тип данных `unknown`. Затем при анализе запроса планировщик уже может решить, что ага, вот здесь этот литерал вставляется в таблицу, у которой тип этого поля должен быть `date` - значит этот литерал тоже должен быть типа `date` и можно попробовать его так интерпретировать.

В большинстве случаев тип для литералов выбирается автоматически.

Однако это может происходить не всегда и может потребоваться привести значение к нужному типу явным образом. Но делать это имеет смысл только тогда, когда без этого запрос не выполнить - то есть СУБД не может определить тип самостоятельно и возвращает ошибку о невозможной операции с подсказкой, что возможно вам необходимо добавить явное приведение типов.

В таблице данные хранятся всегда строго того типа, какого типа объявлено поле. Могу сказать даже больше - без сведений о том, каких именно типов данных записаны строки в датафайлах невозможно эти строки прочитать. Без информации о типах данных полей в хранящейся на диске строке - это просто мешанина лишённых смысла байтов.

Comment: видит некий литерал и для начала считает что это тип данных unknown. А почему unknown? Если я допустим указал (date_start, date) ну явно указал тип.

Comment: потому что "для начала". Запрос сначала надо прочитать и понять что написано, а потом уже думать, что надо сделать для выполнения этого запроса и нет ли в нём неоднозначностей.

Comment: Не очень понял, то есть если я указываю в таблице (date_start date), то столбец date_start это еще не дата, пока я не сделаю приведение?

Comment: ну я же написал что после синтаксического разбора в числе прочих манипуляций определяется, каким типом данных требуется считать этот литерал.

Answer (score 0):

Начну с конца.

В примере с `CREATE TABLE` у Вас в столбце `date_start` хранится дата (он создаётся с этим типом) и при добавление через `INSERT` значение `'2018-02-23'` будет корректно сохранено в виде даты.

В примере с `SELECT '2016-09-12'::date` выводится просто некое скалярное значение, которое не привязано ни к чему (в том числе к таблице). Поэтому просто `SELECT '2016-09-12'` выведет в клиент БД строковое значение и Вы увидите, что-то наподобие "2016-09-12" (по сути это выводимая строка, как она есть). Если же Вы воспользуетесь приведением типов, запрос `SELECT '2016-09-12'::date` выведет уже дату 12.09.2016.

Как-то так.